# Javascript class selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

How come this Javascript selector

`document.getElementsByClassName('first-class class-child second-child')`

looks identical to this jQuery selector

```
$('.first-class .class-chlid .second-child');
```

yet it doesn't work the same way?

Comment: Use `document.querySelectorAll('.first-class .class-child .second-child')`, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll

Comment: Further all answers, you can't use `querySelectorAll` just like you use `$`. You need to use `.forEach`.

Comment: The real answer is because getElementsByClassName does not take a selector at all. Not one of the answers mentions this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) would select an element which has all those space separated classes. Instead use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method which helps to select the elements based on CSS selector.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.first-class .class-chlid .second-child');
```

Answer (score 6):

It sounds like you're looking for [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and/or [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
var matches = document.querySelectorAll(".first-class .class-chlid .second-child");
```

Note that this won't be *identical* to jQuery in the sense that the returned value doesn't have a fluent API for applying changes/effects/etc. to all matched elements.  What you get back here is simply an array of matched elements.  You can do with that array what you wish.

Comment: This doesn't return an `array` but a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList). Minor but important point.

Answer (score 3):

The [`getElementsByClassName` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names.

If you want to "walk" the dom-tree (same way as jQuery does) you should use the [`querySelectorAll` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

```
document.querySelectorAll('.first-class .class-child .second-child')
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from the question if you're looking for the equivalent javascript or the equivalent jquery (even though answer already accepted to make this distinction, if anyone else arrives at this question, they may be looking for the opposite):

The opposite also applies, in that you can change jquery to match `getElementsByClassName` (rather than change to `querySelectorAll` in the javascript)

This code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('first-class class-child second-child')
```

> returns an array-like object of all child elements which have all of the given class names (MDN)

The equivalent in jquery is:

```
 $('.first-class.class-child.second-child');
```

which finds all elements which have *all* of the given class names.

If you wanted to find elements with *any* of those class names, use a comma:

```
 $('.first-class,.class-child,.second-child');
```

Comment: Based on the question I wouldn't assume that the asker is looking for an equivalent to either one at all. All they're asking is why the two statements function so differently despite looking so similar.

Comment: @BoltClock no doubt, but all the other answers provided an equivalent change to the javascript, so I wanted to provide the opposite: an equivalent change to jquery.